Differentiate touchstart + touchend vs. click
With vanilla JS, and no touch framework, what condition makes a touchstart + touchend become a click event?
Is there an official specification like, for example:
touchstart followed by touchend, with delta_time < 100 ms    => triggers a "click" event

?
If so, is the standard followed by Chrome and Firefox?
Example: if  you do a touchstart, then you keep the finger pressed for 2 seconds and then release the finger (touchend), it won't trigger a click.


document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("touchstart", evt => { console.log("touchstart"); }, {passive: true});
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("touchend", evt => { console.log("touchend"); }, {passive: true});
document.querySelector("div").addEventListener("click", evt => { console.log("click"); }, {passive: true});
<div>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello</div>




This is because the system defines the interval needed for an interaction to count as a click, and it does not reveal this interval to the browser to prevent fingerprinting. This is due to accessibility requiring some people with less snappy motor skills to tweak these settings. Therefor, no, you cannot actually distinguish easily. The trick is to cancel events in the touch system so they don't turn into clicks by preventing the browsers default behaviour.

@somethinghere I think you can post this as an answer. Do you have a source that you can link about this information? The fact that the duration for touchstart/touchend can vary from one user to another and also the fingerprinting aspect.

I honestly don't have anything to back it up, it's just something that I noticed after running into this for years simulating a click event myself. I have never ever found a way to let the system tell me what the timing is for a click, so I presume it's for fingerprinting - like most system specific settings. So I'm not going to post this as an answer due to that. I just know from my experience in accessibility that this is configurable. MDN does mention it though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event#usage_notes

@somethinghere I still think it would be a good answer, better than current answers (if you mention it's an hypothesis, it's ok!)

I gave it a shot, but if someone comes along with more in-deoth knowledge I'd be happy to hear from them and give them the credit ;) Cheers

There is no real delta time that you can know about, as this might change from input device to input device and from system to system. In accessibility some people with slower motor skills might have to turn up that delta so their interaction counts as a click. You can see this mentioned in the MDN docs in the Usage Notes and the specification refers to (a term I have never encoutered before but you learn something every day): hysteresis.
In the spec it says that as long as they fall within the same hysteresis it should be considered a click, but the interval between the two events is determined by the system and as far as I know, not revealed through the browser. I presume this is to prevent fingerprinting browsers, although I do think it would be useful if you want to be able to simulate click events yourself (which the specification actually discourages in my quick reading).
Since most people don't switch pointer devices on the fly, perhaps the best way to see what pointer event was likely used is to just match it with CSS: window.matchMedia('(pointer:coarse)').matches should tell you whether it was a touch or a mouse event?


document.addEventListener( 'click', event => {
  
  event.preventDefault();
  
  if( window.matchMedia( 'pointer:coarse' ).matches ){
      
    console.log( 'Probably a touch event click' );
    
  } else {
  
    console.log( 'Probably a mouse event click' );
    
  }
  
})




Here is the documentation. A click event is registered after the touchstart followed by touchend are finished. There is no time limit for the click. Here is the structure: touchstart followed by touchend => triggers a "click" event.

No, if  you do a touchstart, then you keep the finger pressed for 2 seconds and then release the finger (touchend), it won't trigger a click. Your answer is not exact.
